# Merge categories or drop one?

Tags: categorical-data

On seeing the following table, I concluded there is a lot of sparseness in the 'very unsafe' category. My first reaction was to merge it with the 'unsafe' category, leaving me with 3 categories. But another option is to just delete the category. What are the considerations to make before choosing one option? Also, I am wondering if it is ok to keep 2 degrees of safe, and only 1 degree of unsafe. It would, to me, not make much sense when discussing the odds.

[image]

edit in response to Nick Cox:

I assume I should remove the category since the conclusions seem out of line with theoretical expectations. For example, it is assumed that those living in more urban areas experience greater levels of fear. And indeed, the odds of feeling very safe (vs safe) are:
countryside > small city > big city. The odds of feeling safe (vs unsafe) have the same order. But then for unsafe (vs very unsafe) it becomes countryside > big city > small city, which is out of line with theory and the former trend.

I could say that, although urbanisation brings with greater feelings of unsafety, these feeling take on less severe degrees when initiated urbanisation proceeds to higher levels. But of course, I don't want to report such conclusions when these are due to data sparseness rather than social realities.

Comment: Now that I think of it, when merging the categories, I would implicitly conclude that feeling 'unsafe' and 'very unsafe' are similar feelings, but feeling 'very safe' and 'safe' are meaningfully different feelings. Something you can not conclude just from the sparseness. This is probably in favour of dropping it instead of merging.

Answer (score 1):

This is as much social science or psychology (insert your own field if different) methodology as statistics, but

1. The fact that "very unsafe" values are rare is part of the information in your data. As it was presented to the people taking the questionnaire as a possible category, keeping it as a separate category is ideal. It's as interesting as "Yes, the idea of going to Mars knowing that I will die there does appeal" might be as an answer, regardless of the presumably very small number of people who will agree.
2. Merging "very unsafe" and "unsafe" might be forced upon you if whatever ordinal response models you are fitting don't converge or turn out to have very unstable parameters. If your analysis is simpler or more descriptive having some percents small is not fatal, just part of what you have found. Here there is only an allusion to odds, but calculating odds (and related measures) from both fine and coarser versions of the data might make sense.
3. Dropping the "very unsafe" responses -- which you seem to be implying is a possibility -- strikes me as poor social science and poor statistics too. There are few  good reasons for ignoring data, but they do include deciding certain responses are all invalid or all irrelevant to your research problem.

Comment: As I understand it, you are in favour of keeping it. But when analysing (loglinear regression) this category is always contrary to theoretical expectations and the trend between the other 3 categories. Can I be certain this is not due to the sparseness, and these result are trustworthy?

Comment: If you want detailed and well-informed opinions on results of loglinear modelling, please post them. The only reasonable short answer to your last comment is "No"; a better answer depends on much more information from you. Also, we can have no idea of your "theoretical expectations" unless you spell them out.

Comment: Could you have a look at the question edit, whether this is helpful information?

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I don't think I can add anything to my previous comments except emphasis. Your statement "I assume I should remove the category since the conclusions seem out of line with theoretical expectations" is, to be candid, the most disturbing statement I have read for some time about a research project. I'd strongly advise talking this through with a supervisor, advisor or mentor.

Comment: ok, to be clear, I would not have considered removing it if it was out of line with the theory and other trend, when there was no sparseness in the data. These were just additive suggestions that there could be something wrong with the data.

Comment: I'm confused: your position seems either contradictory or too elusive to allow extra comments. I've worked with many social scientists and I think they would all say "so much the worse for the theory" in the information you describe.

Comment: I'm not sure where your confusion comes from. I can only say that at first I was convinced taking it out was necessary, since I was doing analysis on sparse data, which I thought was a no go. E.g. random errors can have severe influence on your results, true variation is missed. You added a third option (next to merging and dropping) which was leaving it as it is. I am now debating whether sparseness is less harmful for the analysis than I first believed.

Comment: We're asked to avoid extended discussions in comments. If your position is clear, it follows immediately that somebody else should be able to understand it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9148/discussion-between-kwanti-and-nick-cox)

Comment: Ordinal response models sound the best way forward for you.